# Need Filter in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, filter, alert

I need my visual content to become darker (like when modal Alert is shown). I've tried to look up in the source code of Alert and PopUpManager, but found only blur and fade effects there... Is there any basic Filter to do set content darker? Thanks

Comment: just make an alert popup and move it off the stage :)

Comment: I'm sure, removing it will hide all filters, I looked up in the source code. But +1 for nice idea :)

Comment: or set the width and height to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ColorTransform` with color multipliers:
`component.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);`

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 styles you can set on the `global` identifier in styles to set all modal popup background effects.  I think you'll want something like this:

```
global
{
   modal-transparency-blur:0; /* no blur */
   modal-transparency:0.5;
   modal-transparency-color:#000000;
   modal-transparency-duration:0; /* no animation, goes straight to faded black.  in ms */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a new UIComponent/Sprite whatever you use, making it black with opacity liek 50% and pushing on top of the display list just below stuff you want to show.

Comment: There's no problem, but why not to use already written things (if there are such)